# What is the form of "売らん" in the sentence "ウランは売らん。"?

Tags: meaning, usage, verbs

I'm not sure if "売らん" is acting as a verb in the dajare, "ウランは売らん。". If it is, please explain what conjugation or form of the verb that this is. If it isn't, can you tell me where "売らん" comes from and what part of speech it is? Can all verbs be put into into this form and what are the peculiarities of their usage?

At first, I thought that "売らん" was only shorthand for "売らない", but I wasn't able to find any information about this on the internet or in any of my books. Afterwards, I tried to do this same kind of modification to another verb in order to see if this form is used with other verbs and "売らん" was not just a single exception. I found the verb "言う" used as "言わん" in many sentences on ALC but it doesn't seem like it is being used directly as a verb by itself. Now, I'm very confused about just what "売らん", "言わん", and other verbs that seem to fit this pattern exactly mean and how they are used. After another bout of search attempts, I still was unable to find any external information about it. Sincere thanks to anyone who can provide me with any information.

Comment: @strawberry jam Thank you very much for linking that other question! I believe that answers my question adequately. Should I delete this question then or wait for other responses?

Comment: Just wait, it will be locked as a duplicate eventually.